# Change color of textview using Animation (Karaoke)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I need to simulate a karaoke in my application.

I also want the user to change the duration of coloring each word (Making the karaoke slower \ faster).

I've read this solution:
[How to make Dynamic change of TextVIew and UI in general?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388341/solved-how-to-make-dynamic-change-of-textview-and-ui-in-general)

Can this solution be replaced by Animation that was presented in API 4.0 ? How can it be done ?

Comment: Your audio question seems unrelated to the title and first question. You should probably post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it so I don't have any code for you really.

But I think you could use 3 `ofInt` ValueAnimator object to go from 0-255 to represent rgb values.

Then at each step you could pass in the rgb values to `Color.rgb(r,g,b);` And pass the result of that to `TextView.setTextColor(int color);`

Comment: My question is how to use Animation to color some of the TextView words in a certain position in time (Like in the link I've posted in my question).